# Regular expression in Python for matching strings in a CSV file

Tags: python, regex

I am working with regular expressions in Python. I want to match a few lines from a CSV file inserted into a database that starts and ends with an underscore.

I have used regular expressions in my Python script to do the same but it prints the result as 'none'. Here is my code for the same, kindly tell me what mistake I am making:

```
reg = re.compile(r'^_.*_$',re.I)
imatch = reg.match(unicode(row[4], "utf8"))
```

Here `r'^_.*_$',re.I` is my regular expression to match lines starting and ending with _. `unicode(row[4], "utf8")` specifies the row from the CSV file inserted into a database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without knowing the contents of `row[4]`, and what you're trying to match. Do you know that there are cases that begin and end with a `_` that are *not* being matched?

Comment: unicode(row[4], "utf8") = ( _aaaaa bbbb ccccc 5635! fgsfrq._ ) Assume this is my string , i want to match few strings like this that starts and ends with _ and it should match with that regular expression

Comment: Why would you expect that to match this regular expression? It doesn't start and end with an `_`.

Comment: Can you give me a proper re syntax for matching if mine is wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to match? You said you wanted to match only lines starting and ending with `_`. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: _ is there before and after the string , its not getting displayed here. i don't know why!

Comment: Wait! do you mean that it is there before and after the string, but it is not getting displayed in your comment? That's because an underscore has special meaning here. Please try putting the string in backquotes- that will format it as code.

Comment: No, that unicode row[4] has the value of a string starting and ending with an _. Iam not able to include _ in the above code here, it's not getting displayed.

Comment: @gayarthi- right, now I understand- for clarity's sake, can you try commenting the value of the string and surround it with backquotes? That will show it without the usual comment formatting.

Comment: @gayarthi: In this case, your problem is impossible to reproduce. `reg.match(unicode("_aaaaa bbbb ccccc 5635! fgsfrq_", "utf8"))` doesn't return None, it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('file.csv')]
for x in lines:
    match=re.search(r'^_.*_$',x)
    if match: print x
```

we have to strip each line otherwise each line ends with char '\n' instead of '_' in that case regex won't match the string.

file.csv

```
_abdlfla_
sldjlfds_
_adlfdls
_132jdlfjflds_
```

output

```
_abdlfla_
_132jdlfjflds_
```

Comment: If you included a sentence about why using _strip_ solves the problem I would be inclined to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You may use startswith and endswith function instead of re. Any specific reason for using re?

```
for l in open('test.csv'):
    l=l.strip()
    if l.startswith('_') and l.endswith('_'):
        print(l)
```